# Definition List in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, plone

Is it possible to activate, create a Definition-List in TinyMCE
"Definition list" is checked in TinyMCE Toolbar settings

plone.app.widgets 1.8
TinyMCE 4.x
Plone 4.3.4

Answer (score 0):

I assume it did not work in your case? right?

First thing you try is to update to the moste recent compatible version for you Plone version and also update Plone 4.3.x to moste recent version.

- Few weeks ago they released `plone.app.widgets 1.9`. They put a lot of effort into it to make it feel more like the Plone 5 version.
- Update to Plone 4.3.10.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me - i don't see a "Definition List"-Button (plone4 or plone5 clean). Is the Defninition List available in TinyMCE 4??